# Not able to recognise url variable in html page in django. Html page is getting generated dynamically

Tags: python, django, web

here is the views.py

```
    def home (request):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        t = get_template('index.html')
        html = t.render(Context({'current_date': now}))
        return HttpResponse(html)

    def run(request, id):
    table=""
    table + = "<table> <tr> <td> <a href= \" /run/{{ id }} \" > "+ linkname + "</a></td></tr></table>"
    return HttpResponse(table)
```

and here is the urls.py

```
    from mysite.views import run
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^home/$',home , ),
        url(r'^run/(?P<id>)$',run),
    }
```

In home page user enters an arguments , run method is called , processes that argument , generates table dynamically on the basis of given argument and responses with the generated table. The table contains a link where i am trying to pass an argument {{ id }}. But when I click the link in the table it gives following error:
The current URL, run/{{ id }}, didn't match any of these.

I am new to django , can anyone help me out

Comment: Why aren't you using an actual template for the HTML in the `run` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not template, This is python string. So you need to use string `fromat`,

Try this way,

```
table + = "<table> <tr> <td> <a href= \" /run/{0} \" > "+ linkname + "</a></td></tr></table>".format(id)
```

Another way:

```
from django.template import Context, Template

def run(request, id):
   table=""
   table + = "<table> <tr> <td> <a href= \" /run/{{ id }} \" > "+ linkname + "</a></td></tr>   </table>"
   t = Template(table)
   c = Context({"id": id})
   return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

Note: I didn't find `linkname` variable. So django throws an error.
[Doc is here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context)

Comment: Ya i forgot to mention linkname variable. Its simple python variable . I'll check and let you know if it works